# Constant Enemy Damage to Player - Unity 2019.1 Beta

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically I have an enemy and a player. When the enemy or player bump into one one-another, the damage occurs and the player is injured resulting in a loss of HP. However, once contact is made, it only damages one time. How to I go about insuring that damage is being dealt to the player non-stop over the duration of the entire length of the collision?

I am  setting up a bool variable isTouching and setting it to true on contact. then set a while loop up that will constantly decrement the player's HP. Then use OnCollisionExit to set the isTouching to false.

```
private bool isTouching; // determines if the player is 
touching
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    isTouching = true;


        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy01")
        {
        while (isTouching == true)
        {
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            HPBAR.PlayHP -= Random.Range(5, 30);
            if (HPBAR.PlayHP < 0)// Insures player HP bar doesn't read less 
            than zero in GUI TXT
            {
                HPBAR.PlayHP = 0;

            }
            // Debug.Log("Ouch! " + HPBAR.PlayHP + " Left");
            if (HPBAR.PlayHP <= 0 && HPBAR.lives > 0)
            {

                HPBAR.lives--;
                HPBAR.LPfloat--;
                p5.transform.position = spawner.transform.position;
                HPBAR.PlayHP = Random.Range(100, 150);
                // Debug.Log("You're Dead!!! Lives left: " + (HPBAR.lives + 1));

            }
            else if (HPBAR.PlayHP <= 0 && HPBAR.lives <= 0)
            {

                SceneManager.LoadScene("DeathScene");

            }
        }//end of while


        } // of player tag check

}// end of collision enter

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    isTouching = false;
}
```

The while loop freezes my computer so I Don't recommend you running it with the while loop on there. Anyway, what I need to know is how to achieve what I'm trying to do. How can I make the enemy constantly damage the player? For example, if I jump on top of the enemy, it'll damage one time then I can ride him around. Which I want damage non-stop to force the player to move off or die eventually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnCollisionEnter2D` is meant to trigger only the first frame the same collision occurs.

You want to use [`OnCollisionStay2D()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay2D.html), which triggers on every frame with a collision.

Also, get rid of the `while` loop. The game can't update (including calling `OnCollisionExit2D`) until the method terminates.

```
private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy01")
    {
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();

        // To take 5 - 30 damage per second:
        HPBAR.PlayHP -= Random.Range(5f,30f) * Time.deltaTime;

        if (HPBAR.PlayHP < 0)// Insures player HP bar doesn't read less than zero in GUI TXT
        {
            HPBAR.PlayHP = 0;

        }
        // Debug.Log("Ouch! " + HPBAR.PlayHP + " Left");
        if (HPBAR.PlayHP <= 0 && HPBAR.lives > 0)
        {
            HPBAR.lives--;
            HPBAR.LPfloat--;
            p5.transform.position = spawner.transform.position;
            HPBAR.PlayHP = Random.Range(100, 150);
            // Debug.Log("You're Dead!!! Lives left: " + (HPBAR.lives + 1));

        }
        else if (HPBAR.PlayHP <= 0 && HPBAR.lives <= 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("DeathScene");
        }

    } // of player tag check

}// end of collision stay

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy01")
    {
        // put "i quit touching the hurty thing" stuff here.
    }
}
```

Comment: OnCollisionStay() Awesome! I haven't heard of this so I'm pretty excited about having new arsenal! I'm going to give this a try and I'll let you know if I encounter and problems. Thanks also for the thorough explanation! I have a much better understanding of the methods now! And definitely was the reason my computer froze.

Comment: If it works be sure to upvote and select it as the answer by clicking the grey checkmark! It helps people with similar problems in the future find this answer and also gives me some internet points :)

Comment: I'm about to click the check in a few moments. The enemy kills my player really fast now. Do I need to set up a CoRoutine to handle the damage at a slower rate?

Comment: Yeah, you could do a coroutine. In that case, you would probably want to go back to using `OnCollisionEnter2D` to start the coroutine, and then `OnCollisionExit2D` change a variable that tells the coroutine to quit looping.  In the coroutine, you could use `yield return new WaitForSeconds(...);` to pick an appropriate "rate" for the damage to hit.

Comment: If you can change your HP to use `float` instead of `int`, you could use `OnCollisionStay2D` and just make the damage numbers really small!

Comment: @AntonioTorro I added some coomments to my answer to explain what I meant. `Time.deltaTime` can be used to make things scale with the framerate so the damage dealt can be expressed in damage per second.

Comment: I didn't think about the Time.deltaTime! Which is insane because that's pretty much how I got me enemies to move randomly, pause, and choose another random direction. Hey brutha, I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: One last question. Is there a way to round the decimals into whole integers? Maybe Mathf.abs() ? Something along them lines?

Comment: HPBAR.PlayHP -= Random.Range(Mathf.abs(5),Mathf.abs(30)); Or is the Time.deltaTime causing the decimals to appear?

Comment: You would have to change `HPBAR.PlayHP` to be a float in order to avoid rounding errors from using `Time.deltaTime`. If you can change it to a float, you can use the code I wrote above to do the damage and use `Mathf.CeilToInt(HPBAR.PlayHP)` when you need to express the HP as a whole number.

Comment: HPBAR.PlayHP actually is a float because this is transferred to the HPBAR script and the information is used as the GUI fillAmount. So in order to get rid of the decimals that's in my HP Bar GUI text, I can use the Mathf.CeilToInt() ? Or would this be unnecessary since it's not an integer value?

Comment: If everything is already using floats, then you won't need `CeilToInt`. Should be fine with only the code in my answer (I edited it again).  I only assumed that it's an integer because everything is comparing it to integers and setting it to integer values.

Comment: Aww man! I gotta stop drinking and coding bro lol I didn't realize the impact that the "f" has on the floating point variables. That should have been more obvious to me! I'm definitely thankful for all of your help!

Comment: HpCounter.text = PlayHP + " / " + PhealthMax; That's how I'm adjusting my GUI text but since it's on the HPBAR script, I didn't need to add the class. However, I'm still getting decimals. Hmmm... I'm not sure what the problem could be. I am thinking that I may need to round the damage off after all. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I misunderstood. Yes you should use `HpCounter.text = Mathf.CeilToInt(PlayHP) + " / " + PhealthMax;`

Comment: That worked like a charm! Now my next question, to better understand the Time.deltaTime. Instead of dealing 5-30 damage, it's only dealing 1-2 damage depending on the length of the contact. What do I need to do in order to insure that it's dealing at least 5-30 damage each collision? Overall I'm not terribly disappointed by these  results, and perhaps I could just make the damage values higher?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185221/discussion-between-ruzihm-and-antoniotorro).

Comment: I actually solved the problem by simply adjusting the damage. Final Solution that worked for me: HPBAR.PlayHP -= Random.Range(25f, 70f) * Time.deltaTime; Once again, thank you for all of your help! I'm officially happy with the script! You've been awesome!